# transaction code "require('@arangodb').db;" can't be packaged

Tags: arangodb, zeit-pkg

zeit-pkg is a tool for package nodejs code. zeit-pkg also support `require('arangojs')`. But zeit-pkg returned error for meet `const db = require('@arangodb').db;` zeit-pkg returns error.

```
> Error! TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    at shortFromAlias (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pkg/lib-es5/walker.js:69:49)
    at Walker._callee5$ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pkg/lib-es5/walker.js:894:25)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pkg/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pkg/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:296:22)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pkg/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:114:21)
    at step (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pkg/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:17:30)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pkg/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:30:13
    at <anonymous>
```

I want to know what's particular in `require('@arangodb').db`. It's whether any replacement method exists for writing transaction. Or any other package tools can support `require('@arangodb').db;`

Answer (score 1):

zeit-pkg is compiles JavaScript code into an executable, this is not compatible with Foxx, as Foxx is the executable that runs your JavaScript code.

If you want to minimize/uglify/mangle your code take a look at WebPack, [this document from ArangoDB](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/foxx-guides-webpack.html) shows you how to get WebPack working with Foxx, as it marks those libraries as 'external' libraries that get skipped for processing.